# How can we write a line ending with " 1" into a file using a Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

#### Short Question

How do I echo the string `"foo 1"` with the `echo` command while redirecting its output to a file such that the entire string is written to the file?

```
C:\>echo foo 1>foo.txt

C:\>type foo.txt
foo

C:\>xxd -g1 a.txt
0000000: 66 6f 6f 20 0d 0a                                foo ..
```

The above experiment shows that only `"foo "` is written to the file because the `"1"` in the command is interpreted to be a part of the redirection operator, `1>`. Note that `echo foo 1 > foo.txt` is not a solution, since it would write `"foo 1 "` to the file with an unnecessary trailing space in the string.

#### Long question

Consider the following Windows batch script.

```
@echo off
call :log "start script"
call :log "foo"
call :log "end script"
goto :eof

:log
echo %~1>>log.txt
goto :eof
```

When I execute this script, it behaves as desired, i.e. write three lines of log in log.txt.

```
C:\>foo

C:\>type log.txt
start script
foo
end script
```

Now consider the following script in which the second line of log has been modified from `"foo"` to `"foo 1"`.

```
@echo off
call :log "start script"
call :log "foo 1"
call :log "end script"
goto :eof

:log
echo %~1>>log.txt
goto :eof
```

This causes a bit of a surprise. As you can see in the output below, we see `"foo"` instead of `"foo 1"` in the log file.

```
C:\Users\pals3\Desktop>foo

C:\Users\pals3\Desktop>type log.txt
start script
foo
end script
```

It's easy to understand why this happens by removing the first line containing `@echo off` from the script, and then executing the script.

```
C:\>foo.cmd

C:\>call :log "start script"

C:\>echo start script 1>>log.txt

C:\>goto :eof

C:\>call :log "foo 1"

C:\>echo foo  1>>log.txt

C:\>goto :eof

C:\>call :log "end script"

C:\>echo end script 1>>log.txt

C:\>goto :eof

C:\>goto :eof
```

As can be seen here, whenever there is `>>log.txt` in the script, the command interpreter replaces it with the synonymous syntax, `1>>log.txt`. This means our command to log `"foo 1"` is now executed as `echo foo  1>>log.txt`, which simply writes `"foo"` to the log file.

A simple solution is to replace the statement `echo %~1>>log.txt` in the script with `echo %~1 >>log.txt`.

```
@echo off
call :log "start script"
call :log "foo 1"
call :log "end script"
goto :eof

:log
echo %~1 >>log.txt
goto :eof
```

However, this means each line of log will be suffixed with a space character which is not ideal from a pedantic standpoint, and a little bit confusing when one might want to filter the log file using grep.

```
C:\>foo

C:\>type log.txt
start script
foo 1
end script

C:\>xxd -g1 log.txt
0000000: 73 74 61 72 74 20 73 63 72 69 70 74 20 0d 0a 66  start script ..f
0000010: 6f 6f 20 31 20 0d 0a 65 6e 64 20 73 63 72 69 70  oo 1 ..end scrip
0000020: 74 20 0d 0a
```

Is there a way to write the `:log` subroutine in a manner that it gets rid of the surprise I've mentioned above while not writing an extra space at the end of every line of log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little-known fact that you can specify the redirection *before* the command:

```
@echo off
call :log "start script"
call :log "foo 1"
call :log "end script"
goto :eof

:log
>>log.txt echo %~1
goto :eof
```

produces:

```
start script
foo 1
end script
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with brackets:

```
@echo off
call :log "start script"
call :log "foo 1"
call :log "end script"
goto :eof

:log
(echo %~1)>>log.txt
goto :eof
```

Comment: This works for most cases but this is not a general solution. It fails when you run: `call :log "(foo)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, this can be used.  Any `)` characters need to be escaped but it leads to a neat block in cases where escaping is not needed.

```
(
echo 123
echo %~1
echo 321
)>log.txt
```